# what is the difference between the below two syntaxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.

```
 $(function () {
       function foo() { return true; }
       log(bar());                        // getting error
       var bar = function() { return true; };   
  });
```

2.

```
$(function () {
        function foo() { return true; }
        log(bar());                        // working 
        function bar() { return true; };  
});
```

in above snippets **log** is my custom function to log the result.

Comment: Please ask coding questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you create an account there, I'll migrate this question for you

Answer (score 8):

In the second, the function `bar()` is hoisted to the top of your function block (all functions declared in a block using this syntax are hoisted to the top of the block) and thus exists before you call it in `log(bar())`.  In the first, the variable bar is not set to your function until after your call to `log(bar())`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block bar is a function variable that obeys scope. In the second code block is a globally declared function because it is not placed inside a scoped variable.

Answer (score -1):

In the first, you have called an variable as an function.

```
long(bar);
var bar=function() {return true;};
```

try this in first one.